# iOS: dynamic height UIScrollview autolayout

Tags: ios, dynamic, autolayout, scrollview

I making a article detail view like Facebook.
This view have content(profile image, writer, date, content text) and comment write view.
So Top view is `UIScrollview`, Bottom view is UIView.

`UIScrollView` have `UIImageview`, `UILabel*3`,
`UIView` have `UITextView`, `UIButton`.

When touch `UITextView` in `UIView`, the keyboard comes up.
So `UIScrollview` will be smaller and `UIView` position will be moved.
And User will write text, `UITextView` line will be added so `UIView` Size will be extended.

Eventually `UIScrollview` and `UIView` height not Determinate.

How to set autolayout this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having UIView for textView and button, what i would suggest you is, just add one scrollView set its constraints as below

[image]

Then add a UIView as container view inside scroll view, (select scroll view go to Editor, select Embed In, and select View) and set its constraint as below

[image]

Now add your imageView, labels, textView and button one by one, and make sure your set imageView's top space to view and button's (which is at the bottom of screen) bottom space to view, and all other view's top space and bottom space to their nearest views, this way scroll view can easily determine the height required for it.

One last thing, when user click inside textView you might need to move scrollView upward in order to make textView visible to user while he is typing, to do this one easy solution is just download the library 'TPKeyboardAvoiding' from [here](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) add all classes to your project and once done, set your scrollView's custom class to 'TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView'. Clean and run the project, it should work..

Answer (score 0):

May try it:
What I say below is about constraint:
UIScrollView top, left, right equal self.view top, left, right
UIScrollView bottom equal UIView bottom
UIView left, right, bottom equal self.view left, right, bottom UIView height equal 200(you set it)

OK, when you UITextView is touched, set the UIView height constraint to what you want(maybe 300)

I think it works!